# Fail to access API when using IdentityServer 4 on a MAC

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have 2 ASP.NET Core 2.1 applications (Auth and API) using Identity Server 4.

On API application Startup I have the following:

```
services
  .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(x => 
    x.ApiName = "api";
    x.Authority = "https://localhost:5005";
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
  });
```

On Auth application Startup I have the following configuration:

```
services
  .AddIdentityServer()
  .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
  .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
  .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())    
  .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
  .AddTestUsers(Config.GetTestUsers());
```

Where Config class is the following:

```
public class Config {

  public static List<ApiResource> GetApiResources() {
    return new List<ApiResource> { 
      new ApiResource("api", "API Resource")
    };
  }

  public static List<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() {
    return new List<IdentityResource> { 
      new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
      new IdentityResources.Profile()        
    };
  }    

  public static List<Client> GetClients() {
    return new List<Client> { 
      new Client {      
        ClientId = "app",
        ClientName = "APP Client",        
        ClientSecrets = { new Secret("pass".Sha256()) },
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,         
        AllowedScopes = { 
          "api"
        }
      }
   }

  public static List<TestUser> GetTestUsers() {
    return new List<TestUser> { 
      new TestUser { 
        SubjectId = "1", 
        Username = "john", 
        Password = "john", 
        Claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("name", "John") } },
    };
  }

}
```

With Postman I am able to access `.well-known/openid-configuration` and create an Access Token.

However, when I call the API I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden by default. 
Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden by default. 
Set the 'ShowPII' flag in IdentityModelEventSource.cs to true to reveal it.]'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I ran `dotnet dev-certs https --trust;` and the localhost certificate appears on Mac Keychain.

**Important**
On a Windows computer the code I posted works fine.
I am able to access `.well-known/openid-configuration` and the API endpoint.

What am I missing?

Comment: TLS version? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: I am not sure what to try ... You mean in Identity Server there is an option do define TLS version? Do I need to export the certificate to a PFX file? I checked the Mac Keychain and the certificate is there ...

Comment: where are the api and idp server host ? That seems certificate problem .

Comment: @NanYu I am launching the API and IDP server using Visual Studio Code on my Development Machine (a Mac). So I am not even hosting them on a server ...